# Guava: Splitter and considering Escaping?

Tags: java, guava

I am interested in the Splitting possibility of Guava:

```
Splitter.on("|").split("foo|bar|baz");
// => "foo", "bar", "baz"
```

This works correctly.

What now if I want to split on "|" but not between "[" and "]":

```
Splitter.on(something).split("foo|ba[r|ba]z");
// => "foo", "ba[r|ba]z"
```

From what I understood, it is not possible to define this "something" in Guava.

I found this:
[Issue 799: Add google escape library to Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=799). Is this related ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using the Guava splitter. The Google escape library is unrelated. It lets you escape HTML, XML, and so on.

Comment: Open issue on Guava's splitter/Joiner: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/412

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to deal with this is to make a parser. It's really easy nowadays, just use a parser combinator, such as JParsec. You'll get something like this:

```
class ParserFactory {

    Parser escapedSequence() {
        return Parsers.between(Scanners.string("["), 
            Scanners.anyCharacterButNot("]"), Scanners.string("]"));
    }

    Parser chunk() {
        return Parsers.or(escapedSequence(), Scanners.anyCharacterButNot("|"));
    }

    Parsers wholeThing() {
        return Parsers.separatedBy(chunk().plus(), Scanners.string("|"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed :) ..  but sometimes it changes the entire design and flow plus one more dependency.. If those are not the concerns then definitely this is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code which works for given use case (Used existing Splitter code as a reference)

```
public class Splitter {
private final CharMatcher trimmer;
private final CharMatcher startTextQualifier;
private final CharMatcher endTextQualifier;
private final Strategy strategy;

private Splitter(Strategy strategy, CharMatcher trimmer, CharMatcher startTextQualifier, CharMatcher endTextQualifier) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
    this.trimmer = trimmer;
    this.startTextQualifier = startTextQualifier;
    this.endTextQualifier = endTextQualifier;
}

private Splitter(Strategy strategy) {
    this(strategy, CharMatcher.NONE, CharMatcher.NONE, CharMatcher.NONE);
}

public Splitter trimResults(CharMatcher trimmer) {
    checkNotNull(trimmer);
    return new Splitter(strategy, trimmer, startTextQualifier, endTextQualifier);
}

public Splitter ignoreIn(CharMatcher startTextQualifier, CharMatcher endTextQualifier) {
    checkNotNull(startTextQualifier);
    checkNotNull(endTextQualifier);
    return new Splitter(strategy, trimmer, startTextQualifier, endTextQualifier);
}

public Splitter ignoreIn(char startTextQualifier, char endTextQualifier) {
    return ignoreIn(CharMatcher.is(startTextQualifier), CharMatcher.is(endTextQualifier));
}

public Splitter trimResults() {
    return trimResults(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE);
}

public static Splitter on(final CharMatcher separatorMatcher) {
    checkNotNull(separatorMatcher);

    return new Splitter(new Strategy() {
        @Override public SplittingIterator iterator(Splitter splitter, final CharSequence toSplit) {
            return new SplittingIterator(splitter, toSplit) {
                @Override int separatorStart(int start) {
                    boolean wrapped = false;
                    for (int i = start; i < toSplit.length(); i++) {
                        /**
                         * Suppose start text qualifier = '[' and end text qualifier = ']' then following code
                         * doesn't address cases for multiple start-end combinations i.e it doesn't see whether
                         * end is properly closed e.g. for configuration like - {@code
                         * Splitter.on("|")..ignoreIn('[', ']').split("abc|[abc|[def]ghi]|jkl")
                         * results -> abc, [abc|[def]ghi], jkl
                         }
                         */
                        if (!wrapped && startTextQualifier.matches(toSplit.charAt(i))) {
                            wrapped = true;
                        } else  if (wrapped && endTextQualifier.matches(toSplit.charAt(i))) {
                            wrapped = false;
                        }
                        if (!wrapped && separatorMatcher.matches(toSplit.charAt(i))) {
                            return i;
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                }

                @Override int separatorEnd(int separatorPosition) {
                    return separatorPosition + 1;
                }
            };
        }
    });
}

public static Splitter on(final String separator) {
    checkArgument(!separator.isEmpty(), "The separator may not be the empty string.");
    checkArgument(separator.length() <= 2, "The separator's max length is 2, passed - %s.", separator);
    if (separator.length() == 1) {
        return on(separator.charAt(0));
    }
    return new Splitter(new Strategy() {
        @Override public SplittingIterator iterator(Splitter splitter, CharSequence toSplit) {
            return new SplittingIterator(splitter, toSplit) {
                @Override public int separatorStart(int start) {
                    int delimiterLength = separator.length();
                    boolean wrapped = false;

                    positions:
                    for (int p = start, last = toSplit.length() - delimiterLength; p <= last; p++) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < delimiterLength; i++) {
                            if (startTextQualifier.matches(toSplit.charAt(i))) {
                                wrapped = !wrapped;
                            }
                            if (!wrapped && toSplit.charAt(i + p) != separator.charAt(i)) {
                                continue positions;
                            }
                        }
                        return p;
                    }
                    return -1;
                }

                @Override public int separatorEnd(int separatorPosition) {
                    return separatorPosition + separator.length();
                }
            };
        }
    });
}

public static Splitter on(char separator) {
    return on(CharMatcher.is(separator));
}

public Iterable<String> split(final CharSequence sequence) {
    checkNotNull(sequence);

    return new Iterable<String>() {
        @Override public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return spliterator(sequence);
        }
    };
}

private Iterator<String> spliterator(CharSequence sequence) {
    return strategy.iterator(this, sequence);
}


private interface Strategy {
    Iterator<String> iterator(Splitter splitter, CharSequence toSplit);
}

private abstract static class SplittingIterator extends AbstractIterator<String> {
    final CharSequence toSplit;
    final CharMatcher trimmer;
    final CharMatcher startTextQualifier;
    final CharMatcher endTextQualifier;

    /**
     * Returns the first index in {@code toSplit} at or after {@code start}
     * that contains the separator.
     */
    abstract int separatorStart(int start);

    /**
     * Returns the first index in {@code toSplit} after {@code
     * separatorPosition} that does not contain a separator. This method is only
     * invoked after a call to {@code separatorStart}.
     */
    abstract int separatorEnd(int separatorPosition);

    int offset = 0;

    protected SplittingIterator(Splitter splitter, CharSequence toSplit) {
        this.trimmer = splitter.trimmer;
        this.startTextQualifier = splitter.startTextQualifier;
        this.endTextQualifier = splitter.endTextQualifier;
        this.toSplit = toSplit;
    }

    @Override
    protected String computeNext() {
        if (offset != -1) {
            int start = offset;
            int separatorPosition = separatorStart(offset);
            int end = calculateEnd(separatorPosition);
            start = trimStartIfRequired(start, end);
            end = trimEndIfRequired(start, end);
            if (start != end)
                return toSplit.subSequence(start, end).toString();
        }
        return endOfData();
    }

    private int calculateEnd(int separatorPosition) {
        int end;
        if (separatorPosition == -1) {
            end = toSplit.length();
            offset = -1;
        } else {
            end = separatorPosition;
            offset = separatorEnd(separatorPosition);
        }
        return end;
    }

    private int trimEndIfRequired(int start, int end) {
        while (end > start && trimmer.matches(toSplit.charAt(end - 1))) {
            end--;
        }
        return end;
    }

    private int trimStartIfRequired(int start, int end) {
        while (start < end && trimmer.matches(toSplit.charAt(start))) {
            start++;
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

}

Small test -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Splitter splitter = Splitter.on("|").ignoreIn('[', ']');
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(',').join(splitter.split("foo|ba[r|ba]z")));
    // yields -> foo,ba[r|ba]z
}
```

Please note - this code isn't tested and does not address all the cases, feel free to modify as per your need.

Comment: See @nes1983 [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755365/guava-splitter-and-considering-escaping/10774702#10774702) as well.. that should be preferred generally.

Answer (score -1):

Guava splitter is very powerful, it can handle regex separators, it can split into maps and more. But what you are trying to achieve is really out of scope of any generic parser.

You want a splitter with on/off switch. I believe the only way to do it is manually, something like this:

```
    List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
    int b=0;
    int j=0;
    String str="foo|ba[r|ba]z";
    int e=str.indexOf('|');
    do{    

      if(b>j)
      {
      j=str.indexOf('[',j);

      while(j>0 && e>=j){
        j=str.indexOf(']',j);    
        if (j<0){
         ls.add(str.substring(b));
         return ;
         }
        j=str.indexOf('[',j);    
      }
      }
      ls.add(str.substring(b,e));
      System.out.println(str.substring(b,e));
      b=++e;
      e=str.indexOf('|',e);
    } while( e >= 0);
```

(Disclaimer: this code is just for giving an idea, it is not working)