# Search for specific parts in a string

Tags: java, android

So im making this txt document that a string writes too with diffrent information about 100-2000 lines . From this I want to be able to copy specific parts such as a name and write them too a new file so I was wondering if someone could help do a example

I want just name,adress and phone pullout of a string as example downbelow and write it to a file :

```
nameadress=johndoe&adress=newyork163thdowntown&phone=+341431242
```

basicly I want 
find nameadress ,adress ,phone copy everything between = and &

and so on and if there's garbage data inbetween i want that ignored :) so I only get these :)

Comment: in android app u wanna do this?

Comment: Yes :) learning android so this is a fun project for me too try out but i got stuck on how to do it for android as the examples i find aren't exactly how I want it done and I dont know how to make the logic :(

Comment: @AmazingHorse Split the string by `&`, then split each chunk by `=`

Comment: Is there a way to make it more versitile and by searching for nameadress=and just coping everything from =  to & ?

Comment: I think you'll find your question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129996/how-do-i-create-a-regular-expression-for-this-in-android

Comment: Can you create an example ? :) Couldnt exactly understand how that wokred

Comment: use any of the parse methods from URLEncodedUtils: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse(java.util.List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>, java.util.Scanner, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `str.split()`:

```
String str = "nameadress=johndoe&adress=newyork163thdowntown&phone=+341431242";
String[] firstSplit = str.split("&");

System.out.println(firstSplit[0]); // Prints nameadress=johndoe
System.out.println(firstSplit[1]); // Prints adress=newyork163thdowntown
System.out.println(firstSplit[2]); // Prints phone=+341431242

String name = firstSplit[0].split("=")[1]; // johndoe
String address = firstSplit[1].split("=")[1]; // newyork163thdowntown
String phone = firstSplit[2].split("=")[1]; // +341431242
```

Then you can write these three strings to a file

In order to ignore any other data you could do the following:

```
String str = "nameadress=johndoe&age=15&sex=female&adress=newyork163thdowntown&phone=+341431242";
String name = str.split("nameadress=")[1].split("&")[0];
String adress = str.split("adress=")[1].split("&")[0];
String phone = str.split("phone=")[1]; // This is the end of the String so we do not need to split("&")
```

Comment: oh nice solution! :) might be an stupied question now but what happens if there is garage data inbetween for example name and adress such as sex and age and I dont want them :nameadress=johndoe&age=15&sex=female&adress=newyork163thdowntown&phone=+341431242

Comment: do you have a well-defined structure for what the data can be?
because currently it is linked to the index.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, in that case, `firstSplit[1]` would be `age=15` and `firstSplit[2]` would be `sex=female`. Everything else would get bumped down 2 indices in the firstSplit list to make space for the two new pieces of data.

Comment: oh going too try it :)

Comment: Updated my post also :)

Comment: I have updated my answer now. Make sure to accept it if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you'd want a parser for. See this answer for a good example of using the Guava libraries. [Guava: Splitter and considering Escaping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755365/guava-splitter-and-considering-escaping)

You would be able to use that to split your string by the '&' characters (and take into account any escape character you use). Once you have split them into:

```
nameadress=johndoe

adress=newyork163thdowntown

phone=+341431242
```

it is fairly simple to further split each string with the Guava Splitter class.

Alternatively, you could instead serialize to JSON, which there are libraries for.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try it but is there a way doing this without importing extenal libs? :)

Comment: You could write your own parser rather easily. Essentially going through each character and checking if it is '&', and whether or not the previous character is an escape character or not. If it is a valid separator character, you break off the characters you've read into a new string, and continue.


Though I usually recommend importing the Guava libraries to any Java project, because they are incredibly useful.

Comment: Any links on how too do it ?  I've tried  Guava and it works for spliting the words without a hitch but I would love to learn the logic behind how do everything :)

Comment: I don't know of any simple implementations which could serve as an example, sorry.